# JQueryUI accordion changestart event - how to get data out of it?

Tags: jquery-ui, accordion

http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#event-changestart

I'm trying to have an JQuery ajax request get some data and populate the body of a div inside each of my JQueryUI accordion rows when the row is expanded. My intention is to have a hidden field, or some such, within the clickable h3's of the accordion and when the changestart event fires the ajax will go off and get a unique page for that accordion row and fill it with useful html.

My problem is that I can't seem to find any information about the properties or values attached to the objects returned in the changestart event function parameters.  Does anyone know how to do this or get those values?

The code I have right now is this:

```
$("#accordion").accordion({
                collapsible: true,
                active: false,
                changestart: function(event, ui) {
                    alert('hello:' + event.target.id + ':' + ui.id);
                }
            });
```

Which throws up an alert displaying the message `hello:accordion:undefined`

I've seen this post which seems to be along the lines of what I'm trying to figure out...
[jQuery UI object type for "ui" object passed to the callback function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2027516/jquery-ui-object-type-for-ui-object-passed-to-the-callback-function)

Thanks,

Matt.

Comment: The answer to this post was very help, btw: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/208016/how-to-list-the-properties-of-a-javascript-object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `ui` holds this:

```
$('.ui-accordion').bind('accordionchangestart', function(event, ui) {
  ui.newHeader // jQuery object, activated header
  ui.oldHeader // jQuery object, previous header
  ui.newContent // jQuery object, activated content
  ui.oldContent // jQuery object, previous content
});
```

Comment: Yes, but what are those for?  For example, ui.oldHeader appears to have a lot of properties, but none of them have anything to do with the html inside my header which was clicked on previously. It does not provide an id, for one.

Comment: More to the point, how do those properties help find the html dom object which was selected and subsequently fired the changestart event?

Comment: The `changestart` event is bound to the accordion not the element that began the process. How about subscribing to the `click` event of the `h3` s in question...

Comment: Thanks - that was what I was looking for; I hadn't realised what was being bound etc...

Answer (score 1):

You can access the contents of those ui.new|old elements easily.
They are jQuery elements, that is why they look a bit odd.

jQuery way

```
ui.newHeader.first().html()
```

And if you need access to the dom element use .get()

```
ui.newHeader.get().first()
```